# Кластеризация бинарных строк

Tags: алгоритм, кластеризация

Будем считать расстояние между двумя битовыми строками равным числу позиций, в которых значения битов у этих строк различаются. Например, расстояние между строками 10001 и 11011 равно двум, а между строками 10001 и 01010 — четырем. Требуется разбить заданный массив строк на максимально возможное число кластеров так, чтобы расстояние между строками из разных кластеров было не меньше трех. 
Формат входного файла: на первой строке — разделенные пробелом число битовых строк n и число бит в строке m; на каждой следующей из n строк — битовая строка, заданная последовательностью из m нулей и единиц (см. примеры по ссылкам выше). Алгоритм должен вычислять число кластеров, сами кластеры возвращать не нужно.

Подскажите подход к решение задачи? Как эффективнее решать?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку у вас задано межкластерное расстояние, а конкретное число кластеров при этом неважно, то можно воспользоваться алгоритмом выделения связных компонент.

Суть его заключается в следующем:

1. Исходные данные представляются в виде графа. Вершины -- это исходные объекты, веса рёбер -- это расстояния между объектами. Естественно, каждая вершина соединена с каждой.
2. Из графа удаляются все ребра, веса которых больше заданного значения (в вашем случае больше 2).
3. Граф разваливается на несколько [связных компонент](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0), каждая из которых представляет отдельный кластер.

Такой алгоритм хорошо сработает, если ваши исходные данные четко бьются на кластеры.

Comment: Вообще непонятно, имеет ли задача решение в общем случае... Например, возьмем для простоты, скажем, все 16 чисел от 0000 до 1111. Удалим все ребра >=3. Все равно все числа будут одним связным компонентом (см. код Грея).

Comment: @Harry этот метод хорошо выделяет кластеры типа сгущений и лент. Последовательность -- это как раз лента, поэтому получится один кластер. В данном случае это недостаток, конечно. Данные обычно не случайны и имеют некоторые особенности. Исходя из этих особенностей и подбирается нужный алгоритм и его параметры. Одним из источников для принятия решения об алгоритме служит гистограмма попарных расстояний. В случае ленты она будет ровной. А для алгоритма выделения связных компонент лучше всего подходят данные с двумя пиками (один -- это внутрикластерные расстояния, второй -- межкластерные).

Comment: @Harry решить же задачу в общем случае для рандомных данных сложновато: придется динамически выбирать алгоритмы и не факт, что получится хороший результат. Что у вас в задаче? Есть какая-то особенность в данных?

Comment: У меня? ничего, это не моя задача. Меня просто заинтересовал ваш метод, не более того. Захотелось просто растолкать небольшой набор данных вручную - и тут у меня ничего не получилось. Вот я и задумался, а что будет в общем случае. Получается, при наличии цепочки решение не существует в принципе...

Comment: @Harry ой, простите, не обратил внимания на ник, подумал, что вы автор вопроса :). Если в данных одна цепочка, то надо либо менять метрику, чтобы получить новую форму кластеров, либо использовать алгоритмы типа k-средних, но быть готовым к тому, что они вам эту ленту просто разобьют на N кластеров, и вы всегда найдете некоторое количество объектов из разных кластеров, у которых расстояние не (сильно) больше внутрикластерного.

Comment: @andreycha, я примерно так и реализовывал, если я Вас правильно понял. Асимптотика получается O(n^2) из-за построения полного графа. На данных из 200к строк данный подход будет работать очень медленно. Есть ли какое то более быстрое решение?